# Netflix Won't Play on Firefox 56.0.2

Tags: firefox, netflix

I have received Netlifx error code F7701-1003 when trying to view Netflix videos on my iMac.  I have gone through all of the steps that Netflix offers:  I am running 56.0.2, the latest version of Mozilla Firefox; I have unchecked and re-checked the DRM enabled box; I have looked for the latest version of Widevine and it is telling me that Widevine is up to date as of today, October 31st.  What else can I do to get Neflix to play?

Comment: Netflix say that they do not support Custom versions of Firefox. It maybe that the Ubuntu Modifications in Firefox maybe telling Netflix something odd. If you can make Netflix work on Chrome / Chromium, then it looks like a Firefox / Netflix issue, rather that Ubuntu.
So, disabling / removing the Ubuntu Modification in Add Ons may well do the trick.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 Firefox 56.0 (56.0+build6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) with Widevine 1.4.8.1008, and the Ubuntu Modifications, even the default user agent plays Netflix for me.

Comment: It works for me on one 64 bit machine, but I can't get it to work on the other.  Bizarre.  Chrome plays it fine on both.

Comment: I was able to play Netflix material using Safari as the browser on the same computer.  How can I disable or remove the Ubuntu Modification? Might doing that affect other video playback?

Comment: Did you try `sudo add-apt-repository universe` then `sudo apt install libavcodec-extra` or `sudo apt install libavcodec` ?